# Ora-01722: invalid number with same datatype

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing an issue that is puzzling cause when I try to select into a value into variable but keep getting an error:

> ORA-01722 invalid number.

Perplexing part is that the source column is the same type as the variable.

```
select distinct bt.id into l_id
       from tb bt,
            rt rt
      where bt.basic_info_id=rt.basic_info_id
        and bt.party_number= '0000';
```

Comment: `bt.id` probably return at least 1 character which isn't a number

Comment: what are the datatypes of your `bt.basic_info_id`, `rt.basic_info_id`, `bt.party_number` and `bt.id` columns, along with that of the variable you're storing the returned value into?

Comment: Can you show l_id definition?

Comment: @user7294900 the characters are all numeric

Comment: the datatypes are both varchar2

Answer (score 1):

Possible issue and resolution:

1. You must declare `l_id` as `tb.id%type` in declare section of your PL/SQL block.
2. `basic_info_id` in both the tables have same data type. If not, cast them using proper method in your query. Like if one is `number` and one is `varchar/varchar2` then use `to_char` on `number` column.

And impotant tip, use standard ANSI joins (`INNER JOIN, LEFT OUTER JOIN, ..`)

Cheers!!